# Why does a zero-dimensional irreducible space have no non-trivial open subsets?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry, dimension-theory-analysis, krull-dimension

Let $X$ be an irreducible topological space. Define the dimension to be the supremum of the length of chains,
$$
Z_{0} \supset Z_{1} \supset \cdots \supset Z_{n}
$$
of distinct, irreducible closed subsets. If $X$ has dimension $0$, why are the only open sets itself and the empty set? I feel like I am very close, but I just can't find a nice proof for it. Say there was a non-trivial open subset $U \subseteq X$. Let $Y$ be its complement. I would like to claim that $Y$ would be an irreducible closed subset which would create a chain of lenth $1$. Is somebody able to spell out how to do this?

Comment: Decompose $Y$ in irreducible components and pick one of them.

Comment: I did try to do this, with the goal of forcing a contradiction, but it just became a horrible mess of De'Morgan's laws that seemed to be going nowhere.

Comment: If $Y_1$ is an irreducible component of $Y$ then $X\supset Y_1$ is a chain of distinct irreducibles of height $1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $U\subset X$ is open, then the complement $Z = X\setminus U$ may not be irreducible.

However, if $p\in Z$ is any point, then the closure $\overline{\{p\}} \subset Z$ is an irreducible closed set.  Therefore, if $X$ is irreducible of dimension zero, we must have $Z=\emptyset$ or $Z=X$.